# .NET Core 2.2 Different time zones in local and Docker

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm running a .NET Core 2.2 app on a Windows machine and somewhere in the code I deal with `TimeZoneInfo` because I need to convert to Spanish times.

I listed the available Time Zone Infos in the system and got a bunch of them and the one I was interested in was the "`Romance Standard Time`". When I deployed to production on a Docker container I found that I got an exception because that time zone was not found. Listing the time zones available in the container I got "`Europe/Madrid`" as the one I needed. My question is, is it because I have a Windows box and somehow has an "old" or "different" timezones installed/configured? Is there a way to have the same set of timezones?

For reference, the Docker image I'm using:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with the underlying OS. Windows has another time zone concept as Linux. The `Europe/Madrid` is a [IANA](https://iana.org/time-zones) time zone name.
I suggest to use the same underlying OS or use the [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) to convert the time zone names.

Comment: I also recommend putting the time zone into a config parameter so you can use a parameter on deployment that differs from local.

Comment: Thanks! the TimeZoneCoverter solved my problem. Fantastic package. Thanks for the quick reply!